# How to send auto email from mail chimp that triger from the wordpress site

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

I've wordoress site for magazines that have email subscriptions for selecting magazines. subscribers will will add to the mail chimp subscription groups according to the selecting magazines. 
Magazines will be uploaded to wordpress back end plugin. I want to send auto email for those people who subscribe to that magazine in mail chimp.

Is there any way to do that? I mean trigger mailchimp auto email according to the wordpress form submit.

Comment: write a php file who sends the emails. Add a cron task which'll call this php file.

Comment: Thanks for idea but this should use via mail chimp

Comment: You have to call mailchimp right ? without user's interactions ? If so the cron is my best guess. It's kind of a planned task and this is the best way to call a PHP script without any user's interaction. It will be call at a given interval.

Comment: Main point here is users have to ability to use custom email templates. That's why we use mail chimp.

Comment: .... describe me how do you send mail with mailchimp at this point ?

Comment: Currently we I'll set up campaign in mail chimp using segments. I want do that auto when some action trigger. Ex: when upload new magazine went to send auto email all subscribes that who subscribe to that mail.

Comment: When you upload a new magazine. Do you do this using wordpress ?

Comment: yes. It is wordpres customize plugin.

Comment: ok so you should be able to make a hook function. Or if it's your own plugin to write code just after the magazine is submited ? right ?

Comment: yes. actually not my plugin. I've used plugin call "participants-database" however i need trigger mail chimp when magazine is upload. and I'm not much familiar with the hook function

Comment: http://xnau.com/work-2/wordpress-plugins/participants-database/participants-database-1-5-api/ It seems that you have 2 hooks you can use. Hooks provide data to a function at a specific point in the execution of the plugin. To use this you'll have to create your own plugin relying on both hooks. And in your hook you make your call to your mail api.

Comment: Thanks for the information. using hook can i get data when form is submit?

Comment: yes, this is the point of using a hook

Comment: Sorry, can you show me how to use that in code. I've no idea how to use it

Comment: http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-use-wordpress-hooks/

Comment: In this plugin there is a filter as "pdb-before_submit_update" - 
provides access to the raw POST array before it is processed and saved to the database. This filter is active for both frontend and admin record updates. 
I've make below in `functions.php`  how could I acces to post array?
`function getmaguser() {
    
}
add_action('pdb-before_submit_update', 'getmaguser');`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
add_action('pdb-before_submit_update', 'getmaguser');
function getmaguser($data) {  print_r($data); print_r($_POST);     }
```

Comment: how to call this? I mean what is the `$data` that pass to this function? can I call this in template file and view the array?

Comment: you can try as I say the best place to put this is to make your own module. But if you want to get it done as quickly as you can try to put this in your template file and see how it behaves

Comment: Thanks but what is the `$data` you pass to function here? what should I pass when I call the `getmaguser` function?

Comment: the getmaguser function is your hook. Here you'll put your call to the chimpmail API.

Comment: In other words this is the place you want to launch the "email for those people who subscribe to that magazine in mail chimp."